# How to run a java from another file?

Tags: command-line, java

I have seen some java applications which I don't type the command in the shell to run it, but when i click a file, it runs the java application. I have only tried

```
javac myjava.java
java myjava
```

Typing this entire command on the shell. Can I make it run when a file is clicked? I am new to Linux. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `javac myProg.java` it creates `*.class` file. That's the actual executable that runs. The bellow solution allows opening a terminal window and running `*.class` file.

1. Create a new desktop file

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/runJava.desktop
   ```

   with the following contents:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=runJava
   Terminal=true
   Exec=bash -c "FILE=%U;cd $(dirname $FILE );java $(basename $FILE .class);$SHELL"
   ```

   Save the file.
2. Right click on any `*.class` file, select `Properties` menu, and change default application to `runJava`

   [image]
3. When done selecting, close the `Properties` menu, double click the file. *Remember: only *.class files that have main method will run*